# Corrupted USB flash drive, cannot initialise or mount

Tags: usb, disk-utility

I have a USB flash drive which seems to be very corrupted. I didn't have any important files on it so I'm not trying to recover files, I just want to get the drive working again. First, whenever I insert the drive, I get this window.
[image]
I press `initialize...` and I go into Disk Utility.
However, Disk Utility says the USB drive is still unmounted.
[image]
As you can see I cannot press mount at all.
Erasing gives me this error.

Erase process has failed. Press Done to continue.

`Unmounting disk
Wiping volume data to prevent future accidental probing failed.
Operation failed...`

Help would be very appreciated. Is this drive broken or can I bring it back to life? :)

Comment: tbh, they're not worth the effort once they start to play up.

Comment: If I'm worried about the data, I hit them with a hammer repeatedly, or run a drill through them several times. Once they go, they are **done**.

Answer (score 2):

You could likely get a 3rd party disk repair utility (Diskwarrior, etc.) but you might be throwing good $ after bad, especially considering the cost of thumb drives these days.

If you have access to a PC you could try formatting it on that. If that fails, toss it.

But really it sounds like the drive is toast.